# $S \in \mathcal{L}(L^1(\Omega))$, find $T^* \in \mathcal{L}(L^\infty(\Omega))$ with $T^*g = Sg \forall g \in L^1(\Omega) \cap L^\infty(\Omega)$

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces, lp-spaces, dual-spaces, adjoint-operators

Below I will bring a passage from Heat Kernels by Wolfgang Arendt (Theorem 4.3.3, page 52). I need to understand it and write a more verbose report based on the chapter, however I am stuck at this part. I managed to repeat most of the steps, but the "this shows" (highlighted with **!!!**) sentence confuses me. How was the author able to do this argument? What does the observation do in this proof? I see that it has something to do with dual spaces and Banach adjoints ($\langle Ax,x^*\rangle = \langle x,A^*x^*\rangle$) and that the integral should be understood as a $L^1(\Omega)^* \cap L^\infty(\Omega)^*$ function (aka $\langle x, x^*\rangle$), but I can't understand where all this is going.

> Let $S \in \mathcal{L}(L^1(\Omega))$ be positive such that $\lVert S\rVert_{\mathcal{L}(L^1(\Omega))}, \lVert S\rVert_{\mathcal{L}(L^\infty(\Omega))} \leq M$.
>
> We have to show that there exists a unique operator $T \in \mathcal{L}(L^\infty(\Omega))$ such that $T^*f = Sf$ for all $f \in L^1(\Omega) \cap L^\infty(\Omega)$. Then we let $S_\infty = T^*$. Uniqueness of T is easy to see. In order to prove its existence we note that the hypothesis implies that $S(L^1(\Omega) \cap L^\infty(\Omega)) \in S(L^1(\Omega) \cap L^\infty(\Omega))$ and $\lVert Sf\rVert_{L^p(\Omega)} \leq M\lVert f\rVert_{L^p(\Omega)}$ for $p = 1, \infty$ and for all $f \in L^1(\Omega) \cap L^\infty(\Omega)$.
>
> Observe that a function $g \in L^\infty(\Omega)$ is in $L^1(\Omega) \cap L^\infty(\Omega)$ and $\lVert g \rVert_{L^1(\Omega)} \leq M$ if an only if
>
> $\lvert \int_\Omega g(x)\phi(x)dx \rvert \leq M\lVert \phi \rVert_{L^\infty(\Omega)}$
>
> for all $\phi \in L^1(\Omega) \cap L^\infty(\Omega)$. **(!!!)** This shows that the adjoint $S^* \in \mathcal{L}(L^\infty(\Omega))$ of $S$ leaves $L^1(\Omega) \cap L^\infty(\Omega)$ invariant and that $\lVert S^*f\rVert_{L^1(\Omega)} \leq M\lVert f\rVert_{L^1(\Omega)}$ for all $f \in L^1(\Omega) \cap L^\infty(\Omega)$ **(!!!)**. By density of $L^1(\Omega) \cap L^\infty(\Omega)$ in $L^1(\Omega)$, there exists a unique operator $T \in \mathcal{L}(L^1(\Omega))$ such that $Tf = S^*f$ for all $f \in L^1(\Omega) \cap L^\infty(\Omega)$. This implies that $T^*g = Sg$ for all $g \in L^1(\Omega) \cap L^\infty(\Omega)$.

Answer (score 0):

Let us denote by $T$ the anti-linear isomorphism
$$T: L^\infty(\Omega)\rightarrow (L^1(\Omega))^*, g\mapsto \left( \varphi\mapsto \int_\Omega \overline{g(x)}\varphi(x)dx\right).$$
When we are talking about $S^*f$ for $f\in L^\infty (\Omega)$, then we really mean $T^{-1} S^* Tf$.

So, the actual claim we want to prove is that $(T^{-1} S^* T)(f)\in L^1(\Omega)$ and
$$\Vert (T^{-1} S^* T)(f)\Vert_{L1(\Omega)}\leq M \Vert f \Vert_{L^1(\Omega)}.$$
Now we compute for $\phi\in L^1(\Omega)\cap L^\infty(\Omega)$
\begin{align*}
\left\vert \int_\Omega \overline{(T^{-1} S^* Tf)(x)} \phi(x) dx \right\vert
&=\vert (S^* T f)(\phi)\vert \\
&=\vert (Tf)(S\phi)\vert \\
&=\left\vert \int_\Omega \overline{f(x)} (S\phi)(x) dx \right\vert \\
&\leq \Vert f \Vert_{L^1(\Omega)} \Vert S\phi\Vert_{L^\infty(\Omega)} \\
&\leq (M \Vert f\Vert_{L^1(\Omega)}) \Vert \phi\Vert_{L^\infty(\Omega)}.
\end{align*}
Using your fact with $g=\overline{T^{-1} S^* T f}$ yields
$$\Vert T^{-1} S^* T f\Vert_{L^1(\Omega)}= \Vert \overline{T^{-1} S^* Tf}\Vert_{L^1(\Omega)}\leq M \Vert f\Vert_{L^1(\Omega)}.$$